# lock MapView movement

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a MapView which has an overlay which consists of a number of drawables which can be selected and dragged around.

The problem is that when an object is dragged the MapView will move as well.

Is there a way that I can lock the MapView?

I have tried using `map.setClickable(false)`

I have also used:

```
        map.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Both attempts do not lock the movement but do disable the ability to select overlays.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Might be worth taking a look into the [new Maps API (v2)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker), as markers are designed to be interactive and come with a `draggable` flag indicating whether the user can change the position of the marker: *"Setting a marker's `draggable` property to `true` allows the user to change the position of the marker"*.

Answer (score 0):

In my old project I set `MapView.clickable(false)` and add layout over that `MapView`. Not sure that is the best solution.

**UPDATE:**

```
<RelativeLayout
            a:id="@+id/map_block"
            a:layout_width="fill_parent"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                a:id="@+id/map_holder"
                a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                a:layout_height="150dp"
                />

        <!-- Layout for catching clicks -->
            <TextView
                a:id="@+id/map_click_receiver"
                a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                a:layout_height="150dp"
                />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add `MapView` in `map_holder` programmatically:

```
mMapView = new MapView(mContext, getString(R.string.gmaps_key));
mapHolder.addView(mMapView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Oh yes and (but I think `mMapClickReceiver.setClickable(false)` can help also):

```
    mMapClickReceiver.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // something to do
                    }
                });
```

Comment: How did you add a layout over your mapview?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
map.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true;
        }
        return v.onTouchEvent(event);
     }

});
```

Comment: Basically instead of `return false` let the view handle the event